# Windows 10 sdk offline installer?

Tags: windows-10, offline-files, sdk

Isn't there any **offline installer** available for the Windows 10 sdk? All I can found is 1.2 MB sized sdksetup.exe file which requires an Internet connection to install. If there available, please provide the link.

Comment: is the question answered?

Comment: can any pls use the official installer and select "installation on a seperate machine" option. So that all the files are downloaded. Then upload the complete installer and share its link. because the official installer doesnt seam to be working for we, it gets stuck in the downloadings saying missmatch hash, tried 10 times atleast and on 2 michines i have

Comment: @Gkills I'm willing to bet that Microsoft prohibits that somewhere in their license agreement.

Answer (score 15):

There is no offline installer/ISO since Windows 8. Go to a PC with a fast unlimited download, run the Installer and select `Download the SDK - Windows 10 10586 for installation on a separate computer`

[image]

This downloads all files and you can use tools like [Folder2Iso](http://www.trustfm.net/software/utilities/Folder2Iso.php?b2=1) to create an ISO based on the folder to use it on different PCs.

Comment: I suppose the download size is **722.4 MB**.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 10 SDK offline installer is available from [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

[image]

You can download the ISO and use it for offline installation. Its size is 643MB.

Comment: ISO is not available now. User has to be use the online installer.

Comment: It is curious that [Russian version](https://developer.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) of this page has a [working link to ISO file](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=859887). The interface language is still English.

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/

Answer (score 0):

**Want UWP Tools and Windows 10 SDK Offline**

First Download Windows 10 SDK from: -

[Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Windows 10 SDK offline installer that will download 700 MB of files and we can use those files to intall Windows 10 SDK to another PC.

After installing Windows 10 SDK we need to install UWP tools for Windows 10.
From this link we will get UWP Tools offline: -

[UWP tools installer](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AppnmrbvPRejhR4NdD1_oc703X-s)

After downloading you find **windows_vstools.exe**.
Go to the directory where you save UWP Tools installer i.e. **windows_vstools.exe**.

Now **Shift Key + Right Click** and select **open command window here**

CMD will open.

And type: -

**windows_vstools.exe /Layout** and press Enter.

After that installer will ask you for download Location i.e. Where to save UWP Tools files.

Then click download.

After downloading finish you can install UWP tools on multiple PCs.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP is looking for an offline installer that works **without an internet connection**.