# Windows 10 SDK offline installer

Tags: windows, sdk

Based on the question asked here [Windows 10 sdk offline installer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1020732/windows-10-sdk-offline-installer?newreg=ee8cfc9d921e4923ab57443b31a3dc1f)

I want to know how to link the downloaded SDK to my visual studio installation.
I already have the sdk downloaded for offline but I still can't create new projects of universal apps in VS2015 community edition (update 2).

I'm trying to avoid having to install the sdk by downloading during vs installation.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions about programming tools are on-topic at Stack Overflow, where you'd probably get better answers.

Comment: I think I'll have to copy/paste this to Stack overflow. Unless there's another way to migrate questions.

Answer (score 0):

During the Visual Studio setup, choose `Custom` to install the Tools for Universal Windows Apps by selecting `Universal Windows App Dev Tools`.

[image]

This is required to build Windows 10 UWP apps. The `Universal Windows App Dev Tools` entry will also install SDK parts which it needs.

Comment: From the question: "I'm trying to avoid having to install the sdk by downloading during vs installation"

Comment: My VS installation is from an iso image file. I don't want to tick the Universal Tools during installation cos it makes no difference - it fails without internet connection. If there's a way I could download the Universal Tools from my office and install it offline on my home computer, that's exactly what I need. I downloaded something I thought was an offline version of the sdk but after installation, it doesn't make any difference in VS. I still can't create Universal Apps for Windows 10.

Comment: vote for offline download here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/13453152-offline-windows-10-sdk-and-uwp-tools